# How to set the size of gridview using a percentage?

Tags: c#, gridview, size, pixel

How to set the size of gridview by percentage in C# ? I would like it to work on all screen sizes?

Comment: you need to specify **winforms** somewhere for clarification, everything here (title, text, tags) can be perfectly applied to webforms as well...

Comment: I was just checking the rating and how it works and mistakenly click down button, apologize for my mistake and thank you for your quick reply :)

I am using windows application forms .net 4 for desktop application.

Answer (score 2):

Use Anchors

You can use Dock, or for more precise control use the Anchor property. By setting Anchor to Left, Right, Top, Bottom the control will scale with the window. By setting Anchor to Right the control will move with the right border. By setting Anchor to Top and Bottom the control will scale vertically, but have a fixed width.

```
myGridView.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
```

Docking Alternatively

```
myGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed but my problem is that I found the exact pixel of the gridview for the form perfectly fit on my laptop screen, but when someone else open on different screen size than the gridsize is misaligned.

Comment: I have check the dock and anchor but it does not work for me.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4ca0d8zyfs4e3q0/_e5JKEnvqz/Binding%20Snaps#/

Have a look on my grid. This grid looks perfect on my laptop screen but they open the another LCD, grid size varied. Now I need to set the width and height of the grid in percentage so that I will work for all LCD nd laotop screen. Thank you.